# Ordering a has_many_belongs_to Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I currently have two Models through a HMBT.  The real problem with this is that I'm trying to figure out a good way to order them.

My one model is a Playlist, the other model being Song.  Ideally, I would have something like:

```
Playlist:
   name: "Playlist Name"
   song_ids: [1,2,3]

Song:
   id: 1
   name: "Song Name
Song:
   id: 2
   name: "Song Name 2"
Song:
   id: 3
   name: "Song Name 3"
```

That way I could just treat song_ids and easily edit/replace it.  FWIW, I would only ever use Playlist#Songs.  I don't think I'd ever use Song#Playlists.  This is also how my I'm serializing my data which is eventually being handled be an Ember.js front-end

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "a good way to order them", how do you want them ordered?

Comment: I'd like to be able to pass an array to song_ids, and that sets the order of the songs instead of using say a third column on an inner join